# How to auto grow (width) of a div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div

```
<div id="div1">
</div>
```

and i am inserting text into it using jquery :

```
$('#div1').html('abcd');
```

I want width of this div expands resize according to length of th text inserted.
I tried :

```
   #div1
{
width:auto;
}
```

but it is not working.
Please help.

Comment: it should work, show us exact code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you want here is `inline-block`. I've made a JSFiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yumEH/1), which should do what you want. Type into the textbox and see the div underneath expand as the text does.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="input">

<div>
    <div id="out"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#input").keyup(function() {
    $("#out").html($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: http://xhtml.com/en/css/reference/display/ The answer is correct, the problem is that a div got display:block by default which makes its width: 100% of its parent item.

Comment: @Aaron it's a hack for ie 7 and lower.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It is working but if i set it's posiiton absolute then it is not working.Please help in resolving this.

Answer (score 2):

The default width of a `div` is `auto` which means "the width of the parent".

If you need an element which changes width according to its contents, you need an inline element like `span`.

The only non-inline HTML element which scales with its content is a `table`. If you don't specify a width for a table, it will grow with its content.

Answer (score 2):

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/9LAg9/2/

Answer (score 2):

My Requirement was same and little different and also want to it work same in ie7+.

Requirement was width according to its content and auto center the div.

Check this out working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/gAcjn/3/

Tested IE7 IE8 IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Don't leave that poor little `div` all alone.

Just put another one next to it like this, or your lonely div will expand to the width of the window. Also, the default value for a `div`'s width is auto, so no point specifying that.

```
<div style="float:left; border:1px solid #fa0237;">Your inserted text</div>
<div style="float:left;"></div>
```

The 2nd `div` pushes up against the right of the 1st `div`, forcing it to assume its minimum allowed width.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with CSS, use `fit-content` property of `width`, like below:

```css
#div1 {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

This will allow the `div` element to auto grow.

---

P.S. : No need of complex JQuereis. Let me know if this was helpful to you.